# How to input strings in Julia from command line

Tags: compilation, julia

I am building a shippable app with Julia using the PackageCompiler.jl library.

https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl

I have followed the example here and got it to run as expected:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl

I am now trying to modify the code piece by piece to replace the toy function with my own function. It involves reading a CSV file into a dataframe whose path is taken from the command line. For now, I am just trying to accomplish this task.

I have this code in `MyApp.jl`:

```
module MyApp

using Example
using HelloWorldC_jll
using Pkg.Artifacts
using DataFrames, CSV, Statistics  

fooifier_path() = joinpath(artifact"fooifier", "bin", "fooifier" * (Sys.iswindows() ? ".exe" : ""))

function julia_main()
    try
        real_main()
    catch
        Base.invokelatest(Base.display_error, Base.catch_stack())
        return 1
    end
    return 0
end

function real_main()
    # @show ARGS
    # @show Base.PROGRAM_FILE
    # @show DEPOT_PATH
    # @show LOAD_PATH
    # @show pwd()
    # @show Base.active_project()
    # @show Threads.nthreads()
    # @show Sys.BINDIR
    # display(Base.loaded_modules)
    for arg in ARGS
        println(arg)
    end
    println("this part worked!")


    df = CSV.read(string(ARGS[1]), DataFrame)[10:end-10,:];
    println(df)
    return
end

if abspath(PROGRAM_FILE) == @__FILE__
    real_main()
end
```

I compile the code with:

```
using PackageCompiler;
create_app("MyApp", "MyAppCompiled")
```

and it compiles just fine.

I run it with:

```
julia MyAppCompiled/bin/MyApp <absolute path to csv>
```

and it works up until the dataframe portion, where I get this error:

```
it worked!
MyApp(66457,0x115997dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x1117d9510: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
MyApp(66457,0x115997dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

signal (6): Abort trap: 6
in expression starting at none:0
__pthread_kill at /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib (unknown line)
Allocations: 47484171 (Pool: 47468051; Big: 16120); GC: 49
Abort trap: 6
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? I know I am putting in the proper path because if I incorrectly type the path I get the  " is not a proper file..." message. I've tried calling with relative and absolute paths.

Comment: To help with the debugging process, you might try (A) trying something simpler and more lightweight than `CSV.read` to a `DataFrame` -- say just a plain `readdlm` (from the DelimitedFiles stdlib) to an `Array`, and (B) perhaps not slicing the df right after reading it (e.g., in case it is empty, etc.).